# Receiving messages without port forwarding

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming

I want a server to be able to send a client a message at any time. There may be no messages for several days, yet if one is sent, I want it to be received almost immediately (ideally within 1 second or less). How would I go about this without setting the client up as a server and using port forwarding?

An example of this would be push notifications on a mobile device. Apple can send a push notification to an iPhone almost instantly. However, the iPhone isn't acting as a server. Furthermore, the iPhone may be moving from network to network, and the networks aren't forwarding any ports to the iPhone. How does this work? Assuming there's some sort of persistent connection, how does the solution scale to hundreds of millions of devices connected at the same time?

This question doesn't depend on a particular language. I'm currently working in JS. I'm looking mostly for a conceptual answer, but feel free to answer it in the context of any language if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, once a network connection has been established, data can flow over it in either direction. There is no requirement that a peer be on the "receiving" end of a connection to receive data!

In the presence of a non-cellular network*, iPhone push notifications work by having the device connect to an Apple notification server, then wait to receive data from it. No port forwarding is necessary, as this is an outbound connection from the device. If the connection is lost, the device will reconnect to the server and "check in" to see if it missed anything.

---

*: If the device only has a cellular connection available, making it infeasible to keep a network connection open at all times, it may rely on notifications through the cellular network itself, kind of like SMS. But that's kind of a separate thing altogether.